# How to Compare & synchronize two database schema using PHP Script

Tags: php, sql, database, synchronization, compare

I have a development database and a production database. I have done some changes in development database Now I have to update the production database So I want a php/SQL script to compare and sync the schema for  both databases.

I have research about this but I did not found any PHP/SQL script to achieve my goal. I have found many tools which can do this but I am looking for any script which is able to do that.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP / MySQL Conceptual Database 'Sync' question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6447600/php-mysql-conceptual-database-sync-question)

Comment: I have to compare the database schema not table data So ...

Comment: Can https://github.com/DBDiff/DBDiff help?